# what is maximum character length of email in Azure Custom ADB2C policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

what is maximum character length of email in Azure Custom ADB2C policy

this is my claim type

```
  <ClaimType Id="signInName">
        <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText />
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.+!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="Please enter a valid email address." />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a valid email it should work (ie charachters@domain.com).
B2C doesn't have limitation on valid email address.

Comment: @raghavendra-msft-identity  it is throwing An invalid value was presented for a property when we try to give more than 100 characters

Comment: The maximum valid email address length would be 73 character excluding domain name. Does the email address you are using is a valid one..?

Comment: @raghavendra-msft-identity  this is the sample mail we are using `xxxxxxxxxxx+invasdnvasdasfinvasdasfinvasdasfinvasdasfi677frrrrrrrrryreeeeeeddfdfdfdfdffewce@gmail.com`

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. Please let us know Does the email is a valid one..?

Comment: @raghavendra-msft-identity yes its a vallid one , instead `xxx` my mail id will be there

Comment: + is not supported in email addresses in B2C I believe. I had seen this mentioned somewhere else.